# If $f$ is open and surjective, can i say that $f$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

my try was, take $U$ open in $Y$ then we take $V$ in $X$ such that $V = f^{-1}(U)$, so as $f$ is surjective $f(V) = U$ and if $V$ is not open then $U$ shoudn't be as $f$ is open.

is that correct?

Comment: think about a connected space mapping to a discrete space of the same cardinality

Comment: Even [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

No that's not. Take any set X with at least two elements, and consider the identity of this set, viewed as a map of X endowed with the trivial topology to X endowed with the discrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

$1_X(x) = x$ (clearly even a bijcction, not merely a surjection) from $(X,\mathcal{T}_1)$ to $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ is open iff $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$ and continuous iff $\mathcal{T}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_1$. This follows from the definitions and $1_X[O] = 1_X^{-1}[O] = O$ for all $O \subseteq X$.

So choosing appropriate topologies on the same set we get easy examples of continuous non-open maps and open non-continuous maps. As $1_X$ is a bijection, $1_X$ is open iff $1_X$ is closed, giving us examples of non-closed continuous maps as well, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{0,1\}$ be a topological space with trivial topology and $\{0,1\}^{\delta}$ a topological space with discrete topology. Let $f:\{0,1\} \to \{0,1\}^{\delta}$, $0\mapsto 0$ and $1\mapsto 1$. Then $f$ is open and surjective but $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{1\}$ is not open in $\{0,1\}$ and open in $\{0,1\}^{\delta}$.